# bajar el peso de una imagen Base 64

Tags: javascript, base64

Buen día estoy tratando de bajar el peso de  una imagen en base 64 antes de subirla a la base de datos, mi código es el siguiente
Html

```
    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Cargar foto</label>
                        <div id="div_file">
                            <i class='fas fa-camera fa-md fal-xs' name="cam" id="cam"><label id="texto" class="control-label">
                                 Tomar Foto</label></i>
                            <input name="foto" id="foto" type="file" placeholder="TomarFoto" capture="camera" required onchange="getBaseUrl()">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
                        <div class="form-group marImg borde_d2 imgFondo">
                            <img id="img" height="150" class="marImg2">
                        </div>
```

el codigo con el que realizo el javaScrip es el siguiente

```
    function getBaseUrl() {
    var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]')['files'][0];
    file.width = 200;
    file.height = 200;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var baseString;
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        baseString = reader.result;
           document.getElementById("b64").innerHTML = baseString;
    }; 
    this.resizeBase64Img(linea, 100, 100).then(function(newImg) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = newImg;
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } 
function resizeBase64Img(base64, width, height) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $("<img/>").attr("src", "data:image/gif;base64," + base64).load(function() {
        context.scale(width / this.width, height / this.height);
        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        deferred.resolve($("<img/>").attr("src", canvas.toDataURL()));
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

El problema es que al trasformar el base 64 no se reduce el peso de la imagen

Comment: Al contrario amigo el formato `base64` sera siempre mas pesado que el formato original, porque la codificacion de caracteres es mucho mas larga y pesada, pero creo que es algo de lo que no deberias preocuparte, porque al decodificar la imagen en el otro lado, esta quedara igual de liviana que antes de codificarla en `base64`, en pocas palabras, base64 te permite transportar informacion sin perdida de datos y de forma segura, pero tiene el inconveniente que la carga transmitida es mucho mas grande.

Comment: si deseas de verdad bajar el peso de la imagen entonces si o si habra perdida de calidad en la imagen, la otra opcion es conservar la calidad pero reducir el tamaño de la imagen, que solo es viable hasta cierto punto.

Comment: El formato GIF suele ser más pesado que JPG. Si quieres cambiar de formato, prueba `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.75);`, donde 0.75 es la calidad, puedes ajustarlo hasta que obtengas el resultado deseado.

Comment: Lo que ha dicho `Triby` te debera funcionar perfecto, iba a mencionarlo antes pero ya lo menciono `Triby`

Comment: Gracias triby con canvas funciono de maravilla

Comment: @Triby considera poner una respuesta ocn lo que comentas

Comment: @MRSDYSOTO Me alegra que encontraras la solución gracias a la colaboración de otros usuarios. Considera poner una respuesta más detallada con lo que acabaste haciendo (incluye código a ser posible), de ese modo si otro usuario tiene mismo problema, podrá servirle de ayuda.